# Database connection issue in installing Powerbuilder 8 application to Windows 10

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, windows-10, database-connection, powerbuilder

I'm trying to get a legacy Powerbuilder 8 application to work in a Windows 10 environment. The application has not been installed from any installation package, I simply open it from a network share containing all the necessary files. It works this way in Windows 7 systems. In Windows 10 the app opens fine, but connecting to database fails with error message:
    999: DBMS MSS is not supported in your current installation.
Neither Windows 7 nor Windows 10 workstations have any specific database access drivers installed.
My development environment has Windows 10 and there connection to the database works ok. The database server is installed locally in the dev environment, though.

Comment: What is the database?  What type of connection (native, ODBC, OLE, etc.) is being used?

Comment: The SQL Server is 2008 R2 and the database is set for compatibility mode 8 (SQL Server 2000). The connection set to use MSS.

Comment: Back when I was using it, you had to install the SQL Server files on the client to access SQL Server: http://slapouttech.blogspot.com/2012/04/powerbuilder-and-sql-server-tips-on.html

Comment: As an approach to get rid of the MSS connection I added another connection type (OLE DB) to be configured for the application, and it looked promising at first. The database connection opens and I can get some data from the database. But in some select statements some of the field names are not sent to the SQL SERVER (like "SELECT a, b, , d, , f FROM MyTable) for some reason, causing errors. Not yet investigated what could cause this. The app is based of a framework making it a bit tricky to investigate. If OLE DB is the way to go, then this is what to do next.

Comment: You may wish to consider upgrading to PB2017 from Appeon since it's the only version certified for use with Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks Slapout for your suggestion, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work in this case. The SQL Server client tools (which I guess my app needs to connect SQL Server from Windows 10 client) is contained in the SQL Server 2000 installation media. I was able to get the media to my hands, but in Windows 10 the setup application doesn't start. I tried to start a couple of the .exe files in the media using application compatibility settings, but a call to a whatever dll ended up with an error message & abortion of the setup. It seems to be a hit and miss to get the setup working.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your suggestion! I agree with you that PB2017 is probably the best - if not the only - way to get the app working in Windows 10.

Comment: Yet, as a temporary solution, it would be tempting to have the app running in Windows 10 client like it does in Windows 7 client. At least I would like to understand what has changed (in terms of db connection) between Windows 7 and 10: Why does the db connection work from Windows 7 client and not from Windows 10 client?

Comment: With all comments hard to say if been mentioned but the message you were getting implies that the PowerBuilder Native Driver is missing from the machine having problems. The file might be named like '%MSS%' but might not cannot remember that far back. I've seen some old PB applications run on Windows 10 even though not officially supported- so there's probably a way to solve this. PB2017 is nice software and Armeen Mazda the CEO is running the company like PowerSoft ran PB back in the day- the right way! I'll have to dig through my discs and see if old PB 8 is available, dig for you.

Comment: Here's an update to my issue few months back.
Attempt #1: Upgrade the old MSS to Native client, OLE DB or ODBC. None worked out. They seem to have a restriction in simultaneous handling of a cursor and an update - eventhough they target different tables in the database.
Attempt #2: Upgrade PB 8 --> Appeon PB 2017. On overall this went smoothly, but hit minor compatibility issues with UI logic.

In the end the solution to overcome the error "999: DBMS MSS is not supported.." turned out to be simple: Include file MSVCR71.DLL in the installation.

Answer (score 0):

We had a problem with Powerbuilder 8.4 and 0racle 10 and 11. With  Windows 10 patch 1803. When we copied files to local drive it worked.  We were getting strange data base error.  It had to do with smb version 1. June 30 2018 Windows 10 solved the problems.  If your still having problem this may be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks Don! I actually copied the application files to the local drive of the Windows 10 machine as the first step in testing the problem to be able to try newer test versions of the app without affecting the production app & configuration in the network share. That doesn't affect the db connectivity, so it seems that our problem is not related to the location of the application files.